# Configure QtPackage for Visual Studio by command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt5

I'm trying to build a project which uses qt on an CI service for windows.

I already managed to install the [QtPackage for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=havendv.QtPackage) by command line.
Now I'm stuck at the following step:

> - Launch VS2015 for configuring Qt5Package
> - QT5 > Qt Options > Add
>
>   - Version name: **Qt 5.6.22Win32**
>   - Path: **C:\build\libs\qt5_6_2\qtbase**
> - Default Qt/Win version: **Qt 5.6.2 Win32** – **OK** - You may need to restart Visual Studio for this to take effect.

Is is possible to do this from the command line? If not, how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to modify such global setting (for all projects), I'm sorry but there is no way to do it from command line in current public versions of the QtVSTools, nor in the latest version from the repository head (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/ @ 2018-01-09).

On the other hand, if you use `msbuild` to compile the project, you can override the Qt version to be used during that compilation (project files are not modified).

To do so, change the `QTDIR` project property (using the `/property` option) and indicate the path to the directory of Qt version you want to use:

```
msbuild your_solution.sln /property:QTDIR="C:\build\libs\qt5_6_2\qtbase"
```

Hope this helps.